# How can I get a representative point of a GMM cluster?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, centroid, gmm

I have clustered my data (75000, 3) using sklearn Gaussian mixture model algorithm (GMM). I have 4 clusters. Each point of my data represents a molecular structure. Now I would like to get the most representative molecular structure of each cluster which I understand is the centroid of the cluster. So far, I have tried to locate the point (structure) that is right in the centre of the cluster using gmm.means_ attribute, however that exact point does not correspond to any structure (I used numpy.where). I would need to obtain the coordinates of the closest structure to the centroid, but I have not found the function to do that in the documentation of the module (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html). How can I get a representative structure of each cluster?

Thanks a lot for your help, any suggestion will be appreciated.

((As this is a generic question I haven't found necessary to add the code used for the clustering or any data, please let me know if it is necessary))

Answer (score 14):

For each cluster, you can measure its corresponding density for each training point, and choose the point with the maximal density to represent its cluster:

This code can serve as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
from sklearn import mixture

n_samples = 100
C = np.array([[0.8, -0.1], [0.2, 0.4]])

X = np.r_[np.dot(np.random.randn(n_samples, 2), C),
         np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([-2, 1]), 
         np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([1, -3])]

gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='full').fit(X)

plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:, 1], s = 1)

centers = np.empty(shape=(gmm.n_components, X.shape[1]))
for i in range(gmm.n_components):
    density = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal(cov=gmm.covariances_[i], mean=gmm.means_[i]).logpdf(X)
    centers[i, :] = X[np.argmax(density)]
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], s=20)
plt.show()
```

It would draw the centers as orange dots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find the point with the smallest Mahalanobis distance to the cluster center.

Because GMM uses Mahalanobis distance to assign points. By the GMM model, this is the **point with the highest probability of belonging to this cluster**.

You have all you need to compute this: cluster `means_` and `covariances_`.